# Writing to a file?

Tags: java, android, file

I want to write to a file in Android, but it results in the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File C:/Users/Senior/Downloads/Gps_location-master/DenverCrimeDataVisualization/app/src/main/res/raw/neighborhood_id_location.json contains a path separator

```
private void writeToFile() {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter =
                new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "neighborhood_id_location.json")));

        outputStreamWriter.write("[");

        for (int i = 0; i < geo_lat.length; i++) {
            // Maybe:
            outputStreamWriter.write("{\"lat\" : " + geo_lat[0] + ", \"lng\" : " + geo_lon[0] + "}");
            // Or:
        }

        outputStreamWriter.write("]");
        outputStreamWriter.close();

        outputStreamWriter.write("["+"{"+"Latitude" + geo_lat[0] +  "," +"Longtitude"+  geo_lon[0] +"}" +"]");
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
```

Comment: what does getExternalFilesDir do?

Comment: Try to write result of getExternalFilesDir to File variable and check if it is not null and writable.

Comment: I guess it points to error in JSON file, did you try external JSON parser? Is there something in this file?

Comment: Why does the error mention `C:/...`? You're on Android, it should be something like `/sdcard/...`, right?

Comment: @JonesV The error points to the file in Windows because while compiling the JSON file is stored in provided path. That's why I guess that error is in JSON file. Could you show it up?

Comment: neighborhood_id_location.json is at raw file under layout file. i want to write code on that but it failed